# How to run a REMIX UNIT TEST for 2 Smart Contracts (Token Contract and Staking Contract)

Tags: solidity, remix, unittesting, remix-tests

I have 2 Smart Contracts

Token Contract: A basic ERC20 with 6 decimals 
Staking Contract: A contract which locks in the Token above and requires the Token address to be part of the parameters

I am using REMIX, and I have already successfully run a basic test which allows me to buy tokens (see below)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../contracts/Token.sol";

contract TokenTest is Token{

function beforeAll () public {
    //do something
}

/// #sender: account-1
/// #value: 1000000
function purchaseToken () public payable {
    Assert.notEqual(msg.sender, TestsAccounts.getAccount(0), "Owner wallet cannot purchase");
    buyToken(msg.sender); //token buy function that is payable
    Assert.equal(balanceOf(msg.sender), 10000000000, "Incorrect amount");
}

}
```

The next thing I want to do is test the staking method of my 2nd contract and here is where I am stuck.

Questions:

1. If I import my second contract in the same test file, it gives me error of `DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.`How can I then test the Staking Contract? Should it be in another test file? Will the values from the posted test file carry over the the Staking test file?
2. The examples I have seen from the docs, usually extend the main contract they are testing via `is` eg. `TokenTest is Token`. So I am not sure how to inject my staking contract within the same file.
3. What are the best practices/design patterns to use for doing this in REMIX.
4. Is there a way to 'schedule' events in Unit Tests (eg. call function A of contract every 10 seconds)

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am also open for suggestions if you think other tools are more appropriate for this tasks eg. Ganache/Truffle, etc.

Thank you